# Bootstrap modal('hide') isn't removing all applied attribute properties

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

All right so I have a modal:

```
    <div id="modal-container" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content center-block" style="display: table;">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

On my page I use a button that uses ajax to load the modal content from another page. At the bottom of the page I have 2 buttons. One to close the modal and another to submit the form.

```
<div class="modal-body">
    <div class="form-horizontal">

.....insert rest of the modal content....

        <div class="modal-footer">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" id="approve-btn" value="Create" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-container" class="btn btn-primary" />
                <input type="button" id="cancel-modal" value="Cancel" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-default modal-close-btn" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Hitting close causes no problem whatsoever. The `modal-open` class is removed from the body and the `padding-right: 17px` is removed from the style attribute and the page's content is back to exactly how it was before. Now if I were to click on the submit button, an event handler is called submitting the form using ajax. On success content is added to a table I have, styles are applied, `$('#modal-container').modal('hide');` is called, and 2 more calls are performed unrelated to my question.

```
$('#modal-container').on('submit', '#associatelicensemodalfrm', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var data = $(this).serializeArray();
    $.ajax({
        url: '/software/newpurchase',
        type: 'POST',
        data: data,

        success: function (data) {
          .... code involving my table and transforming the data....
            table.row.add(row).draw();
            $('.date-picker').datepicker();
            $('#modal-container').modal('hide');
            $('#compliancefieldsfrm')[0].childNodes[1].children[2].innerText = aggregateQuantityPurchased();
            calculateCompliance();
        }
    })
});
```

I have an event handler rearing to go once `modal('hide');` is called. The handler is for the `hidden.bs.modal` event which is called immediately after `modal('hide')` is called unless you have a handler for `hide.bs.modal`. Then it's called right after that one.

```
//clear modal cache, so that new content can be loaded
$('body').on('hidden.bs.modal', '.modal', function () {
    $(this).removeData('bs.modal');
    $('.modal-content').html('');
});
```

The code above resets the `.modal-content` div to an empty string along with that first line which I forget at the moment what it does. After this handler finishes up the `modal-open` class is removed from the class attribute, but the `padding-left: 17px` is not removed from the style attribute. If you were to call the modal and submit the form again you would then have `padding-left: 34px`. You can see after submitting this form enough times the whole page now looks like it's left justified which is completely wrong.

I've tried removing the `data-toggle="modal"` from the modal form, but when `$('#modal-container').modal('hide');` runs nothing happens. The hidden event isn't triggered. I tried removing the `$('#modal-container').modal('hide');` and leaving `data-toggle="modal"` and it was still up. Same thing happened when I removed both `data-toggle` and `data-target`. The modal didn't go away. This is how my question is different from the other answers I've seen. Explicitly neither the javascript nor the data attribute way of hiding/removing the modal works. I have to use both, yet the styling doesn't go away. What am I messing up?

Comment: You might find it easier to use something like [Bootbox.js](http://bootboxjs.com), which lets you build your Bootstrap modals as you need them. I can post an example based on your code if you want to go that route.

Comment: @TiesonT. If it solves my problem I'll try out Bootbox.js. I'm fairly surprised no one else has ran into this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out!

I used to use the pagedlist plugin to represent content in a modal and on `loaded.bs.modal` I would call `.removeData('bs.modal');`. That way when more content was loaded when you would click to go to the next page of the table everything would update. That modal isn't needed anymore so I removed that line and it works now.

Answer (score 0):

I've run into this issue only when using modals with async updates.  Add an EndHandler to fix the padding issue.

Note -- in my case it was adding padding-right to the body.  You mentioned padding-left, so you'll need to tweak the below code to correct for that.

In your JS, add:

```
Sys.Application.add_init(appl_init);
function appl_init() {
    var pgRegMgr = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
    pgRegMgr.add_beginRequest(BeginHandler);
    pgRegMgr.add_endRequest(EndHandler);
}
function BeginHandler(sender, args) {
    // Add anything here that you want to occur just before the async post is performed
}

function EndHandler(sender, args) {
    $('body').removeClass('modal-open');
    $('body').css("padding-right", "0px");  // Bootstrap will calc the width of the browser toolbar and add this padding each postback (cumulatively)
    $('.modal-backdrop').remove();
    $('#modal-container').modal('show');  // Remove this line if you do not want to keep the modal open
}
```

You might even be able to just add the first three lines of the above EndHandler to your Ajax Success block.  I've never tried that though so I'm only speculating.